# Meteor 1.3 server testing

Tags: meteor, mocha.js

I'm trying to understand http://guide.meteor.com/testing.html testing guide but honestly I have no idea how to run server side test on mocha driver. Everything is run as Client test and I have 0 tests on "Server tests". 
If I place test file under server/ (`server/users.test.js`) it will be loaded and executed (ie. `console.log('foo')` ) but function inside `describe ..` will not.

EDIT:

```
if(Meteor.isServer) {
  describe('todos', function () {
    describe('mutators', function () {
      console.log(1)
      it('builds correctly from factory', function () {
        console.log(2);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

inside `imports/api/user/users.test.js` printed "1" but not "2"

Comment: Could you show some more sample code to provide a [mcve], allowing us to try and reproduce your issue to then fix it? It also allows future readers to relate more easily to your issue.

Comment: @Kyll having I've found the reason. I had `dispatch:mocha-phantomjs` package installed - don't ask me why  - https://github.com/practicalmeteor/meteor-mocha/issues/23

Comment: As requested in this [Meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326456/how-can-i-post-a-useful-comment-without-reputation), here is a potentially useful link: https://github.com/practicalmeteor/meteor-mocha/issues/42