# Mocha for Meteor not running test reporter

Tags: unit-testing, meteor, mocha.js

My meteor mocha [test reporter](http://guide.meteor.com/testing.html#driver-packages) is not showing up, therefor I can't run my unit tests. What's odd is it runs describe() but not it(); both are from Mocha.

```
console.log('Hello World!'); //this works

import { chai } from 'meteor/practicalmeteor:chai';

describe('Meteor Methods', function () {
console.log('inside describe function!');    // this works

// console.log('it: '+it);
 /*
function (name, func) {                                                                        
I20160613-16:50:40.062(-6)?     // You can create pending tests without a function                                                               //
I20160613-16:50:40.062(-6)?     // http://mochajs.org/#pending-tests                                                                             //
I20160613-16:50:40.063(-6)?     // i.e pending test                                                                                              //
I20160613-16:50:40.063(-6)?     // it('this is a pending test');                                                                                 //
I20160613-16:50:40.063(-6)?     if (func) {                                                                                                      // 57
I20160613-16:50:40.063(-6)?       func = wrapRunnable(func);                                                                                     // 58
I20160613-16:50:40.063(-6)?     }                                                                                                                //
I20160613-16:50:40.063(-6)?     mochaExports["__org_it"](name, func);                                                                            // 60
I20160613-16:50:40.063(-6)?   }
*/


it('unit test I want to work 1', function () {
console.log('before assertion WIN');    // this doesn't work
chai.assert.equal(-1, [1,2,3].indexOf(5));
})

it('unit test 2'); //pending test doesn't work
console.log('after it'); //this works

});

describe("foo", function() {
console.log('inside second suite'); //this works
it("bar", function() {
  console.log('hello?');  // this doesn't
    expect(1+1).to.equal(2);
});
});
```

I've been on this for a couple of days. I've seen this:
 [Meteor 1.3 server testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36593111/meteor-1-3-server-testing)
and this:
https://github.com/practicalmeteor/meteor-mocha/issues/42

OSX El Capitan 10.11.3 | Meteor 1.3.2.4

Tried:

- avital:mocha@2.1.0_10 (https://themeteorchef.com/blog/meteor-1-3-from-a-20-000-foot-view/)
- practicalmeteor:mocha@2.4.6-rc.2 (https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-test-not-running-some-tests-and-not-throwing-errors/21232/3)
- having the tests inside and outside the tests directory
- adding ES6 support
- using phantom instead
- replicating the [todo app](https://github.com/meteor/todos) (working unit tests)
- replicating [this repo](https://github.com/pcorey/practicalmocha-repro) with working unit tests
- copying every package to make it work

Thanks for any help you may provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. For the future, I had to reorder the packages in the packages file to make it work.

Under the `.meteor/packages`, you should find the line with `meteortesting:mocha` and move it to the top. For me, placing it right after meteor's basic libraries worked.

## Before:

```
# Meteor packages used by this project, one per line.
# Check this file (and the other files in this directory) into your repository.
#
# 'meteor add' and 'meteor remove' will edit this file for you,
# but you can also edit it by hand.

meteor-base@1.0.4             # Packages every Meteor app needs to have
mobile-experience@1.0.4       # Packages for a great mobile UX
mongo@1.1.14                   # The database Meteor supports right now
blaze-html-templates    # Compile .html files into Meteor Blaze views
session@1.1.7                 # Client-side reactive dictionary for your app
jquery@1.11.10                  # Helpful client-side library
tracker@1.1.1                 # Meteor's client-side reactive programming library

es5-shim@4.6.15                # ECMAScript 5 compatibility for older browsers.
ecmascript@0.6.1              # Enable ECMAScript2015+ syntax in app code

pack:age
packa:ge
foo:bar
...
meteortesting:mocha
```

## After:

```
# Meteor packages used by this project, one per line.
# Check this file (and the other files in this directory) into your repository.
#
# 'meteor add' and 'meteor remove' will edit this file for you,
# but you can also edit it by hand.

meteor-base@1.0.4             # Packages every Meteor app needs to have
mobile-experience@1.0.4       # Packages for a great mobile UX
mongo@1.1.14                   # The database Meteor supports right now
blaze-html-templates    # Compile .html files into Meteor Blaze views
session@1.1.7                 # Client-side reactive dictionary for your app
jquery@1.11.10                  # Helpful client-side library
tracker@1.1.1                 # Meteor's client-side reactive programming library

es5-shim@4.6.15                # ECMAScript 5 compatibility for older browsers.
ecmascript@0.6.1              # Enable ECMAScript2015+ syntax in app code

meteortesting:mocha
pack:age
packa:ge
foo:bar
...
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you did specifically to fix this?

Comment: Oh man this was a while ago, but from what I remember there were packages that depended on each other so I reordered them in the packages file. Specifically the Mocha package and maybe another testing package like Chai. Once they were in the proper order it worked great.